# How do I revert some changes in my code?

Tags: git, version-control

Imagine I have the following commits on a single branch:

`A-B-C-D-...-W`

On commit B I committed some changes that makes my application use red font. We realized the public wasn't ready for red font so we decided to revert to black font on commit C but knowing that eventually we would change to the red font. Several commits later we're now at commit W and we're ready to institute the new red font. Is there a way I can (or should have) setup my branches better so that I could simply merge in the changes to pick up the change to the red color?

I run into this a lot and find myself just doing a diff between A and B and then manually putting those changes into my working copy and making a new commit X.

Maybe if I had planned better, I should have not continued my branch from B but rather created a new branch from A? Then I would have this scenario:

`A----B
  \
   ---B2-C2-D2-...-W2`

If I were in this scenario I could now just merge the changes from commit B (the new red font) into W2. I'm sure this is obvious to many people but I would appreciate someone chiming in here. My problem is that I often think of these things after the fact. In addition often my commits may include other changes besides this one red font change.

If I were still at the point of being at commit B, should I have rebased to split that into multiple commits with this red font being the final commit? Then branch off my development path from the point (commit A) just before adding the red font?

Given where I am now, is there anything to try other than manual diffs to decide what changes to make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to work after commit `B` but still need to keep the commits from `B` to `W`. If this is your situation, you just need to **checkout a new branch from `B`** (if you want checkout from `A`, you can use similar way) and then work on it. When it’s ready, you can merge the new created branch to your current branch. Details as below:
1.Assumw the original structure is:

```
A---B---C---D---…---W  yourBranch
```

2.Create `newBranch` from commit `B`, and make changes on `newBranch` (commits `B1` to `Bn`):

`git checkout -b newBranch <commit id for A>`

```
A---B---C---D---…---W  yourBranch
     \
      B1---B2---…---Bn    newBranch
```

3.After finish developing on `newBranch`, you can merge it into your original branch (`yourBranch`):

`git checkout yourBranch
 git merge newBranch`

```
A---B---C---D---…---W---M  yourBranch
     \                 /
      B1---B2---…----Bn    newBranch
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but my case was so simple that I didn't even have much parallel development going on after the creation of commit B. In hindsight if I had branched from A I would have saved myself trouble.

Comment: For this situation, with two branches, the only purpose is to keep your current work, so that you can start work on `B` (I updated my answer). And it's highly recommend to work with branches when you develop new features, fix bugs etc.

Comment: After further analysis I think both answers are very helpful but this is probably best. Actually A is the commit before the change and B is the one with it. So I did: git checkout A; git checkout -b BB1; git checkout B . #the dot causes my working directory to be filled with the contents from commit B; git commit -a; git checkout W; git merge BB1. This allows git to see BB1 on its own branch but with common ancestor A.Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you try to cherry-pick B on top of W I think git will tell you that the revision is already applied (because it is part of the history of W, right?) So we have to kind of "fool" git into thinking that B hasn't been applied at all. I would checkout A, cherry-pick B (just to create an exact clone of B but that is a different revision, that should be enough to fool git).. let's call this revision B', then I would checkout W and I would cherry-pick B'.

`git checkout A
git cherry-pick B
git checkout W
git cherry-pick HEAD@{1}`

Comment: The really best approach would have been to remove revision B when you noticed that you wouldn't need it (perhaps setting it on a separate branch) and then there would be no need to create revision C... but then you wouldn't have been able to see it in the history of W to apply the trick I provided as the solution, right? It's got pros and cons (cleaner history but need to save the revision on a separate branch.... we can't expect to always get everything taken care of by git, right? :-))

Comment: Just thought of another way that would work without having to go with the cherry-picking and stuff: just ```git revert C```. That should make it look like B was cherry-picked.

Comment: And, finally, you can always clean up the history of the branch. You can set aside revision B on a separate branch (git branch temp-B B), then checkout revision A, cherry-pick C..W ( so that revisions B and C don't show up on this new history) and then you can cherry-pick temp-B.... that would create something _resembling_: A-D-E-F...U-V-W-B. This is git, so you can always rewrite stuff so have fun (consider that by doing this you are creating new revisions so if people are working on the previous branch, it will take a little extra effort to get things on top of this new branch).